# Using streams to manipulate a String

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Let's say that I want to remove all the non-letters from my `String`.

```
String s = "abc-de3-2fg";
```

I can use an `IntStream` in order to do that:

```
s.stream().filter(ch -> Character.isLetter(ch)).  // But then what?
```

What can I do in order to convert this stream back to a `String` instance?

On a different note, why can't I treat a `String` as a stream of objects of type `Character`?

```
String s = "abc-de3-2fg";

// Yields a Stream of char[], therefore doesn't compile
Stream<Character> stream = Stream.of(s.toCharArray());

// Yields a stream with one member - s, which is a String object. Doesn't compile
Stream<Character> stream = Stream.of(s);
```

According to the javadoc, the `Stream`'s creation signature is as follows:

> Stream.of(T... values)

The only (lousy) way that I could think of is:

```
String s = "abc-de3-2fg";
Stream<Character> stream = Stream.of(s.charAt(0), s.charAt(1), s.charAt(2), ...)
```

And of course, this isn't good enough... What am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an answer the second part of the question. If you have an `IntStream` resulting from calling `string.chars()` you can get a `Stream<Character>` by casting to `char` and then boxing the result by calling `mapToObj`. For example, here's how to turn a `String` into a `Set<Character>`:

```
Set<Character> set = string.chars()
    .mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that casting to `char` is essential for the boxed result to be `Character` instead of `Integer`.

Now the big problem with dealing with `char` or `Character` data is that supplementary characters are represented as *surrogate pairs* of `char` values, so any algorithm with deals with individual `char` values will probably fail when presented with supplementary characters.

(It may seem like supplementary characters are an obscure Unicode feature that we don't need to worry about, but as far as I know, all emoji are supplementary characters.)

Consider this example:

```
string.chars()
      .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
      ...
```

This will **fail** if presented with a string that contains the code point U+1D400 (Mathematical Bold Capital A). That code point is represented as a surrogate pair in the string, and neither value of a surrogate pair is an alphabetic character. To get the correct result, you'd need to do this instead:

```
string.codePoints()
      .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
      ...
```

I recommend always using `codePoints()`.

Now, given an `IntStream` of code points, how can one reassemble it into a String? [Sleiman Jneidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31977402/1441122) is a reasonable one (+1), using the three-arg `collect()` method of `IntStream`.

Here's an alternative:

```
StringBuilder sb = ... ;
string.codePoints()
      .filter(...)
      .forEachOrdered(sb::appendCodePoint);
return sb.toString();
```

This might be a bit more flexible, in cases where you already have a `StringBuilder` that you're using to accumulate string data. You don't have to create a new `StringBuilder` each time, nor do you have to convert it to a `String` afterwards.

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted as IMO it's the most elegant solution which doesn't require a 3rd party library

Answer (score 9):

The method `chars` returns an `IntStream`. You just missing the collector

```
String s = "abc-de3-2fg";
String s1 = s.chars().filter(Character::isLetter)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this seems really verbose (I am not familiar with java 1.8). isn't there something more concise ? Maybe using a reduce method ? With Scala, you could write this like  `"abc-de3-2fg".filter(isLetter).mkString("")`.

Comment: @FrancisToth In Scala, a filter over a string is a string, which is not the case here, chars() here returns an IntStream, and a filter over an IntStream returns an IntStream, there is a reduction method called Collectors.joining() but this requires converting every char into a string

Comment: I am just astonished. I've just made a couple of tries to provide a more concise solution, but without any success (with mapping, toArray, and a bunch of other stuff). I am a Java supporter, but no wonder that Scala is so popular.

Comment: @FrancisToth There's always `int[] filtered = s.codePoints().filter(Character::isLetter).toArray(); s = new String(filtered, 0, filtered.length);`.  No Collector needed.

Comment: @FrancisToth basically, trying to convert a stream to a `String` is seen as an edge case.  (Justifiably so, in some ways.)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately such scenario is badly supported by Java 8 Stream API. My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library adds a couple of helper methods to work with such streams: [`IntStreamEx.charsToString()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#charsToString--), [`IntStreamEx.codePointsToString()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#codePointsToString--) and [`IntStreamEx.toCharArray()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#toCharArray--). Also I introduced the primitive collectors like [`IntCollector`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntCollector.html) which may help collecting the primitive streams in some non-trivial way.

Here's how your task can be solved using the StreamEx library:

```
String result = IntStreamEx.ofChars(s).filter(Character::isLetter).charsToString();
```

Or with codepoints:

```
String result = IntStreamEx.ofCodePoints(s)
                           .filter(Character::isLetter)
                           .codePointsToString();
```

Comment: I tried playing with StreamEx a little bit, looks very good. I'll give it a try :-)

Comment: @KidCrippler, nice to hear. If you have any enhancement suggestions or discover bugs, feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/issues).

Answer (score 1):

```
public String removeNonLetters(String value) {
    return value.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)               // map int to char
            .filter(Character::isLetter)           // filter non-letters
            .map(String::valueOf)                  // required for joining
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```