# How can I convert stream of characters to String?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this `stream`:

```
"hello".chars().filter(c -> c != 'o')
```

What do I have to do to get a new `String` without `o` ?

Comment: any reason you are doing this with a stream instead of regular `replace` operations?

Comment: is String.replace not a better way?

Comment: @GhostCat it's helpful to link to the answer directly; users occasionally change their screen name, but it's also just neat to jump straight there ;)

Comment: @AndyTurner I always wondered how to do that. Oh, there is a *share* link. Would could have thought about that ;-)  ... so the answer that talks about stringbuilder : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31981043/1531124